# How do I separate multiple observations from one column and match them with another column with multiple observations?

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I have multiple observations in cells in two columns. They are recorded in order so each observation corresponds to the other observations in the column next to it.

```
dat <- data.frame(id = c("1,2", "2,3", "3, 4, 5, 6"), 
                  location = c("N,S", "S,N", "N,N,N,S")
                  )
```

I would like to separate the data in these cells, so that the first column will be the number 1-6 and the second with the corresponding location N or S.

I have tried using pivot_longer() and separate_rows(), but still no luck.

Comment: Will they always be consistent? (i.e. will "2" always be "N" within a given dataset?)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `separate_longer_delim` from package **`tidyr`**

```
dat %>%
    separate_longer_delim(everything(), ",")
```

which gives

```
  id location
1  1        N
2  2        S
3  2        S
4  3        N
5  3        N
6  4        N
7  5        N
8  6        S
```

if you want to keep unique rows only, then append `distinct()` to the code above

```
dat %>%
    separate_longer_delim(everything(), ",") %>%
    distinct()
```

such that

```
  id location
1  1        N
2  2        S
3  3        N
4  4        N
5  5        N
6  6        S
```

---

If you prefer **Base R**, you can try

```
type.convert(
    unique(
        list2DF(
            lapply(
                dat,
                \(x) trimws(unlist(strsplit(x, ",")))
            )
        )
    ),
    as.is = TRUE
)
```

which gives

```
  id location
1  1        N
2  2        S
4  3        N
6  4        N
7  5        N
8  6        S
```

Comment: Thanks this worked pretty much perfectly. I was getting an error when using distinct() `Error in UseMethod("distinct") : 
  no applicable method for 'distinct' applied to an object of class "NULL"` . However I just used `|> unique` instead and that did the trick.

Comment: @Puzzler which version of `dplyr` are your using? If it still gives an error, then `unique` can make it as the same.

Comment: Currently running 1.1.2, but I see 1.1.3 is the current version so I'll update and give it another try.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for

```r
dat <- data.frame(id = c("1,2", "2,3", "3, 4, 5, 6"), 
                  location = c("N,S", "S,N", "N,N,N,S")
                  )

dat <- apply(X = dat, 
             MARGIN = 2, 
             FUN = \(x) unlist(strsplit(x, ","))
             ) |> 
  as.data.frame() |>
  unique()
dat
#>   id location
#> 1  1        N
#> 2  2        S
#> 4  3        N
#> 6  4        N
#> 7  5        N
#> 8  6        S
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

This is an approach in `base R`, no external packages are needed.

W. r. t. @Paul Stafford Allen comment below, you might want to complement with `|> unique()` to obtain every `id` only once, which assumes that the data is consistent.

Comment: Nice answer. I think to fully match the OPs request possibly add a pipe to `dplyr::distinct()` to finish it off?

Answer (score 0):

`lapply` `strsplit` over the columns.

```
> lapply(dat, strsplit, split=',\\s*') |> sapply(unlist) |> as.data.frame() |> type.convert(as.is=TRUE)
  id location
1  1        N
2  2        S
3  2        S
4  3        N
5  3        N
6  4        N
7  5        N
8  6        S
```

You can pipe into `unlist()` if needed.